# Drop Duplicate Rows in Excel based on Column Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, boolean

I am attempting to use pandas to drop duplicate entries in an excel document based on very specific conditions. Here is an excerpt from my dataframe:

```
       WD    MSN    TAIL REV
3425  30-11-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3426  30-21-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3427  31-31-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3428  31-31-41  26154  N754CX   A
3429  31-31-41  26154  N754CX   B
```

As you can see, I have two copies of `WD` `31-31-41`, and I want to keep only the newest revision, REV B. However, several different "MSN" numbers may also have this WD, and I do not want to affect those entries. Furthermore I want this code to do this for all past revisions, regardless of MSN or WD. For instance, another MSN may have multiple revisions of 32-46-11, and I would need to keep only the newest one.

I have found how to find duplicates in my dataframe using the following:

```
df.iloc[3425:3430 , 0:4].duplicated(["WD","MSN"],'last')
```

Which outputs:

```
3425    False
3426    False
3427    False
3428     True
3429    False
dtype: bool
```

But this only shows the first entry as a True, but as these are being entered in by a human, the last entry may not necessarily be the newest revision.

Comment: Will you please provide a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Hi, one question: if "the last entry may not necessarily be the newest revision", how can you decide which one is the newest or which one to keep?

Comment: To answer richardec:
```            
WD    MSN    TAIL REV
3425  30-11-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3426  30-21-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3427  31-31-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3429  31-31-41  26154  N754CX   B
```
would be my expected output from the sample dataframe. 

To aaossa, the revision levels, from first to last, go IR, A, B, C, etc...
So whichever is the latest in sequence would be the newest. My implication is that I may enter data into this sheet that shows WD REV C, but 400 cells later someone could enter WD REV IR, WD REV A. I would need to keep C and drop the more recently entered...

Comment: ... but out of date revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer that assumes that the last entry is the newest.

```
>>> df.groupby(["WD", "MSN"]).tail(1)
            WD    MSN    TAIL REV
3425  30-11-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3426  30-21-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3427  31-31-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3429  31-31-41  26154  N754CX   B
```

The updated question indicates that the "REV" column has an implicit order, so we can create a [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas-categorical) column with an explicit order:

```
>>> df["REV"] = df["REV"].fillna("Unknown")  # To support NaN values
>>> df["REV"] = pd.Categorical(
        df["REV"],
        categories=["Unknown", "IR", "A", "B", "C"],
        ordered=True,
    )
>>> df.loc[df.groupby(["WD", "MSN"])["REV"].idxmax()]
            WD    MSN    TAIL REV
3425  30-11-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3426  30-21-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3427  31-31-11  26154  N754CX  IR
3429  31-31-41  26154  N754CX   B
```

Comment: I like this solution, and it's what I'm going to use for the time being for sure. If you can review my answer to your comment from yesterday, I think I've explained what I meant.

Apologies, I'm quite new to coding in general and I'm just trying to make things at my job a bit more efficient.

Comment: When I use your updated answer, I get the following error:
```
ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```

Comment: I think this is because in some rows, the REV has been left blank. Is there a way I can ignore blank REVs? If not, I can come up with something to put in that cell that effectively becomes the new lowest revision.

Comment: No, I meant keep them. Like replace every blank REV with "Unknown" and do this:
df["REV"] = pd.Categorical(
        df["REV"],
        categories=["Unknown", "IR", "A", "B", "C"],
        ordered=True,
    )
But that didn't clear my error either, I still get the ValueError

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much for your help!